# ExecuteReader() in Powershell script

Tags: sql, powershell, ado.net, executereader

I'm trying to read data from a SQL table in a powershell script. I can see the data in reader object, but when reading it using `While (readerobject.read()){}`, it's not going inside the loop.

**Powershell**:

```cs
 $cmd = $sqlConn.CreateCommand()
 $cmd.CommandText ="SELECT * from user"
 $movedUserDetails = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
 while ($movedUserDetails.Read())
   {
      "[0] : " + $movedUserDetails.GetValue(0)
   }
 $movedUserDetails.Close()
```

Comment: That should work, although you're not saving the value anywhere.  You can add it to an array object with `+=`.  [Here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2009/04/13/run-a-sql-server-command-from-powershell-without-the-sql-server-provider.aspx)

Answer (score 17):

The syntax is correct, but you're not doing anything with the value once inside the loop.  You'll want to persist it somehow.  Here's an example of running some basic SQL inside of powershell, with two different types of commands (Text/SP) and two different methods of execution (DataAdapter/DataReader).  Either one of each should work fine.

```cs
# config
$svr = "serverName"
$db = "databaseName"

# connection
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$svr;Database=$db;Integrated Security=True"
$sqlConnection.Open()

# command A - text
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection
$sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT name AS TABLE_NAME FROM sys.tables"

# command B - stored procedure
$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection
$sqlCmd.CommandText = "sys.sp_tables"
$sqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@table_owner", "dbo")

# execute A - data reader
$reader = $sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
$tables = @()
while ($reader.Read()) {
    $tables += $reader["TABLE_NAME"]
}
$reader.Close()

# execute B - data adapter
$dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$sqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $sqlCmd
$sqlAdapter.Fill($dataTable)
$sqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: I would use `$tables = while ($reader.Read()) { $reader["TABLE_NAME"] }`.  Array concatenation is an O(n) complexity operation in PowerShell just by itself, so a loop that concatenates output to an array is automatically O(n^2) complexity.

Answer (score 3):

First off, if you're just doing some quick & dirty work with SQL Server or running file-based scripts, save yourself a ton of trouble and just use [`Invoke-Sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd). It's written and maintained by really smart people, so will likely serve you well.

If you're needing to run a lot of queries in a short period and could benefit from reusing your connection. Or want the safety/integrity of parameterized queries, `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` make more sense.

Bearing in mind that PowerShell is a pipeline oriented construct, it behooves us to think in terms of the pipeline and leverage it effectively. That said, rather than dump all of the records into a `DataTable` only to iterate them again downstream, why not leverage the dynamic nature PowerShell and pass a "callback" (i.e. `[ScriptBlock]`) to perform some operation on each `IDataRecord` as you iterate the `IDataReader`.

The following function `Invoke-SqlCommand` requires a: **Connection String, Query and Callback** which can be used for row projection/analysis etc.

> Note: If a persisted `SqlConnection` is required, simply replace the `$ConnectionString` parameter with `$Connection`.

```bsh
function Invoke-SqlCommand {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
               ValueFromPipeline=$True,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,
               HelpMessage="The connection string.")]
    [string] $ConnectionString,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
               HelpMessage="The query to run.")]
    [string] $Query,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
               HelpMessage="The work to perform against each IDataRecord.")]
    [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
  )

  $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  $conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString

  $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
  $cmd.CommandText = $Query

  try {
    $conn.Open()
    $rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

    while($rd.Read()){
        Write-Output (Invoke-Command $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $rd)
    }  
  } 
  finally {
    $conn.Close()
  }
}
```

> Please do not use this in production without specifying a `catch {...}`, omitted here for brevity.

This format affords you the opportunity to perform some operation and projection against each `IDataRecord` AND yield it into the pipeline for downstream processing.

```bsh
$connectionString = "your connection string"
$query = "SELECT * FROM users"
Invoke-SqlCommand $connectionString $query {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader]$rd)

    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ user_id = $rd.GetValue($rd.GetOrdinal("geoname_id"))}
    $obj.psobject.typenames.insert(0,'MyAwesome.Object')

    Write-Output $obj
}
```

The use of `New-Object` here is simply to provide us with consistent field ordering without having to rely on an ordered hash table and helps us identify our custom `PSObject` more easily when running things like `Get-Member`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer below is a but outdated. You should use [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) now.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlStatement -ConnectionString $ConnectionString;
```

You might have to do a `Install-Module -Name SqlServer` to install it.

---

If you don't want to install the `SqlServer` module or your Powershell version is 2 or lower, you can try with a `SqlDataAdapter`. I made this Powershell module to fetch records with SQL. It has never failed me

```
function Invoke-SqlSelect
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    ( 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,Mandatory=$True)] 
        [string] $SqlServer,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,Mandatory=$False)] 
        [string] $Database = "master",
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,Mandatory=$True)] 
        [string] $SqlStatement
    )
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    
    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SqlServer;Database=$Database;Integrated Security=True"
    
    $sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $sqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlStatement
    $sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection
    
    $sqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $sqlCmd
    $dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    try
    {
        $sqlConnection.Open()
        $sqlOutput = $sqlAdapter.Fill($dataTable)
        Write-Output -Verbose $sqlOutput
        $sqlConnection.Close()
        $sqlConnection.Dispose()
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Output -Verbose "Error executing SQL on database [$Database] on server [$SqlServer]. Statement: `r`n$SqlStatement"
        return $null
    }
    

    if ($dataTable) { return ,$dataTable } else { return $null }
}
```

Comment: I'm using this to export the CREATE statements for all stored procedures in a database, but it cuts off the command prematurely. After some spaces it seems.

Comment: @Dieter this code is for select statements only. If you want to execute queries you can use the same code but remove all the lines with `$sqlAdapter` and add `$cmdOutput = $sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` after `$sqlConnection.Open()`

Comment: Please excuse me as I steal this for learning and implementation purposes.  This little snippet is FANTASTIC!  :)

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue and I believe the reason is the following(worked for me):

The database connection is not always closed correct e.g in an error case. If it is not closed it will skip the while loop. Change your code to the following:

```
     $sqlConn.Open()
     $cmd = $sqlConn.CreateCommand()
     $cmd.CommandText ="SELECT * from user"
     $movedUserDetails = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
     try
     {
         while ($movedUserDetails.Read())
         {
           "[0] : " + $movedUserDetails.GetValue(0)
         }
     }
     catch
     {
       #log error
     }
     finally
     {
       $sqlConn.Close() 
     }
```

The finally statement is always executed and will secure that the connection is properly closed.